# How to upload photos from iPhone to cloud using 3G and remove them from device automatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, photos, data-synchronization

I have an iPhone 4S with iOS 9.3 and I want to upload photos right after being taken by camera to any cloud storage automatically, then to auto-remove them from the device. I am using 3G only, not Wi-Fi.

From the research, there are some apps:

- iCloud Photo Library - it does not work via 3G and does not remove photos form the iPhone (only optimize them)
- Dropbox Plus
- Microsoft OneDrive
- Google Photos
- Flickr
- PhotoSync

Anybody has tried any of these (or others) and can tell me if it is possible?

Comment: For one, none of the listed apps will let you automatically delete the photos from the library. Also, none of them except iCloud will continue running in the background till all photos are uploaded (due to background execution limitation imposed on iOS for 3rd party apps).

Comment: @NimeshNeema [PhotoSync](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photosync-transfer-photos/id415850124?mt=8) claims to "automatically backup photos & videos in the background to pre-selected targets (computer, NAS, cloud & photo services)" and "PhotoSync can optionally perform automatic deletion of successfully backed up photos & videos – a convenient way to free up space on your device (iOS 8 and higher)". Can anybody confirm that it works?

Comment: Almost all of the apps listed claim (and perform) automatic backup, with a catch that the app should be running in the foreground. Once the app goes into background, it has a limited time (usually a few minutes) before the uploading stops. I have no idea about PhotoSync performing automatic deletion feature.

Comment: Looks like iCloud photo library will only work over WiFi on iOS 9. This is changed in iOS 11 or 12. As for the optimization, this is how all photo apps will work-in order to show you a preview of what the picture looks like (so you *know* what you're looking at), you have to cache a smaller version. These smaller versions will take up very little space on your phone. All the other apps have to use the photo management API, which requires apps to ask permission each time they delete photos and can only run in the foreground. The other apps may also stop working on iOS 9 once they're updated.